# Clean Cypress cache in GitHub CI

Tags: github, continuous-integration, cypress

I'm running Cypress on Github CI.

I upgraded from version 7 to 8 but tests are still runs on the 7 on.

Can someone told me how do deleting this version?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the command to delete all previously installed versions of cypress.

```js
cypress cache prune
```